# Excel File not Recognized by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The error occurs on the **Open.Workbooks MasterFile** line. I get the error of "This file cannot be found. Has it been removed, renamed, or replaced?" I used the fso.FileExist function to make sure the file does actually exist, and when I debug.print, the file name is exactly as it is specified in the variable MasterFile. Why won't VBA recognize this .xlsm file?

```
Sub ProcessData()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fil As Scripting.File

Dim MyDir As String
Dim FolderSource As Scripting.Folder
'FolderSource is the fso enabled directory folder
Dim FolderDataSource As Scripting.Folder
'FolderDest is the fso enabled folder where the MasterFile is located

MyDir = "C:\Users..."
'MyDir is where all part number files will be stored

Dim MasterFile As String
Dim MasterFilePath As String

MasterFilePath = "C:\Users..."
MasterFile = "Function Master File.xlsm"

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
'The workbook and worksheet source will be the Master FIle

Dim wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet
'The destination workbook and worksheet corresponding to the part number file

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim x As Long

myArray = Range("D13:D17")
'Array will draw from part number values that are entered in the appropriate area on the template

'Creating files for all new part numbers
Set FolderSource = fso.GetFolder(MyDir)
    'For Each fil In FolderSource.Files
        For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            If myArray(x, 1) <> "" Then
                PartNumFile = MyDir & "\" & myArray(x, 1) & ".xlsx"
                    If Not fso.FileExists(PartNumFile) Then
                    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
                        With newbook
                        .SaveAs Filename:=PartNumFile
                        End With

                    End If
            End If
            'Searching for the Part Number Data in the Master File
            Set FolderDataSource = fso.GetFolder(MasterFilePath)
            For Each fil In FolderDataSource.Files
            Debug.Print fil.Name

                If fso.FileExists(MasterFilePath & "\" & MasterFile) Then
                Debug.Print fil.Name
                        Workbooks.Open MasterFile
                        Set wbSource = Workbooks(MasterFile)
                        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
                            lrSource = wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        Set wbDest = Workbooks(myArray(x, 1) & ".xlsx")
                        Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets(1)
                            lrDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        wsSource.Range("A2:V" & lrSource).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lrDest)
                End If
            Next
        Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Workbooks.Open MasterFilePath & "\" & MasterFile`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I get "syntax error" when trying that!

Comment: Try `Workbooks.Open  chr(34) & MasterFilePath & "\" & MasterFile & chr(34)`?

Comment: If you do `Debug.Print MasterFilePath & "\" & MasterFile`, does it show the correct information?

Comment: @AnaliaQuirk If you get `syntax error` from that then there is something wrong with your path. Can you post the output of `MasterFilePath & "\" & MasterFile`?

Comment: As a test, try hard-coding the full location string after `Workbooks.Open`, and see if that works....